# django orm - check if dictionary key exists in a model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a series of dictionaries that I want to save if a unique id for each dictionary doesn't already exist in the database. If it does exist it would be good to check the values for each key are the same as their corresponding value in the database and update if not. 
What's the best way to do this in Django?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
if Thing.object.get(unique_id=dict1['unique_key']):
    thing = Thing()
    thing.unique_id = dict1['unique_key']
    thing.property = dict1['other_key']
    thing.save()
```

I'm not sure how the else block should work?

(Note can the primary key autofield id be non sequential so I can store the unique id from the dict in the default Model id field without needing an additional unique id column?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way to achieve this is to use the update_or_create method in a similar way to Javier's response.

```
thing, created = Thing.object.update_or_create(
    unique_id=dict1['unique_key'], 
    defaults={'property': dict1['other_key']}
)
```

Comment: Wow. I did not know about this. You get an upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to do this:

```
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
# Do NOT do this in your view for every request
# add this to your <app>/forms.py and import it (this is just an example)
ThingForm = modelfor_factory(Thing, exclude=[])
# end

# in your view
thing, created = Thing.object.get_or_create(
    unique_id=dict1['unique_key'], 
    defaults={'property': dict1['other_key']}
)

# already exist
if not created:
    form = ThingForm(dict1, instance=thing)
    # you can also see what changed using `form.changed_data`
    if form.has_changed():
         form.save()
```

Internally it will do exactly what you're trying to do, but its easier on the eyes.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L454

Comment: Thanks .get_or_create() looks perfect for new items - I can't seem to find if there is something like a .get_and_update_if_diff() for already existing instances?

Comment: Ok. That should do it. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not using forms or views here. This is a series of dictionaries generated from JSON via a scraper run via a Django management command.

Comment: You don't have to "use" the form it to save. You can however utilize it; say the 'has_changed' -- otherwise you'll be writing that code yourself. I dont know you but anything i can get free by using something existing - im a happy guy. Then you can use your own `save()`ing logic. My 2 cents..

Comment: Thanks... debating whether I need the if not created section as I think the get_or_create() method will update or insert as needed.  From the notes it mentions that it will create a new object as per the algo mentioned here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create - which uses update.

Answer (score 0):

> can the primary key autofield id be non sequential so I can store the unique id from the dict in the default Model id field without needing an additional unique id column?

Yes, yes, it can. I override the [hash](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) builtin to return unique identifiers for records. A simple **hash** function for a dictionary follows:

```
def __hash__(self):
    hash_value = sum([hash(v) for v in self.values()])
    return hash_value
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure if my question was clear - I already have a unique value from one of the values in the dict.  To answer my own question yes you can set your own primary key - it just needs to be unique not sequential